# How do you use FCKEditor's image upload and browser with mod-wsgi?

Tags: python, django, fckeditor, mod-wsgi

I am using FCKEditor within a Django app served by Apache/mod-wsgi. I don't want to install php just for FCKEditor andI see FCKEditor offers image uploading and image browsing through Python. I just haven't found good instructions on how to set this all up.

So currently Django is running through a wsgi interface using this setup:

```
import os, sys

DIRNAME = os.sep.join(os.path.abspath(__file__).split(os.sep)[:-3])
sys.path.append(DIRNAME)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

In fckeditor in the editor->filemanager->connectors->py directory there is a file called wsgi.py:

```
from connector import FCKeditorConnector
from upload import FCKeditorQuickUpload

import cgitb
from cStringIO import StringIO

# Running from WSGI capable server (recomended)
def App(environ, start_response):
    "WSGI entry point. Run the connector"
    if environ['SCRIPT_NAME'].endswith("connector.py"):
        conn = FCKeditorConnector(environ)
    elif environ['SCRIPT_NAME'].endswith("upload.py"):
        conn = FCKeditorQuickUpload(environ)
    else:
        start_response ("200 Ok", [('Content-Type','text/html')])
        yield "Unknown page requested: "
        yield environ['SCRIPT_NAME']
        return
    try:
        # run the connector
        data = conn.doResponse()
        # Start WSGI response:
        start_response ("200 Ok", conn.headers)
        # Send response text
        yield data
    except:
        start_response("500 Internal Server Error",[("Content-type","text/html")])
        file = StringIO()
        cgitb.Hook(file = file).handle()
    yield file.getvalue()
```

I need these two things two work together by means of modifying my django wsgi file to serve the fckeditor parts correctly or make apache serve both django and fckeditor correctly on a single domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Ultimately I was unhappy with this solution also so I made a [Django app](http://bitbucket.org/megaman821/django-fckconnector/) that takes care of the file uploads and browsing.

This is the solution I finally hacked together after reading the fckeditor code:

```
import os, sys

def fck_handler(environ, start_response):
    path = environ['PATH_INFO']
    if path.endswith(('upload.py', 'connector.py')):
        sys.path.append('/#correct_path_to#/fckeditor/editor/filemanager/connectors/py/')
        if path.endswith('upload.py'):
            from upload import FCKeditorQuickUpload
            conn = FCKeditorQuickUpload(environ)
        else:
            from connector import FCKeditorConnector
            conn = FCKeditorConnector(environ)
        try:
            data = conn.doResponse()
            start_response('200 Ok', conn.headers)
            return data
        except:
            start_response("500 Internal Server Error",[("Content-type","text/html")])
            return "There was an error"
    else:
        sys.path.append('/path_to_your_django_site/')
        os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'your_django_site.settings'
        import django.core.handlers.wsgi
        handler = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
        return handler(environ, start_response)

application = fck_handler
```

Answer (score 1):

This describes how to embed the FCK editor and enable image uploading.

First you need to edit fckconfig.js to change the image upload
URL to point to some URL inside your server.

```
FCKConfig.ImageUploadURL = "/myapp/root/imageUploader";
```

This will point to the server relative URL to receive the upload.
FCK will send the uploaded file to that handler using the CGI variable
name "NewFile" encoded using multipart/form-data.  Unfortunately you
will have to implement /myapp/root/imageUploader, because I don't think
the FCK distribution stuff can be easily adapted to other frameworks.

The imageUploader should extract the NewFile and store it
somewhere on the server.
The response generated by /myapp/root/imageUploader should emulate
the HTML constructed in /editor/.../fckoutput.py.
Something like this (whiff template format)

```
{{env
    whiff.content_type: "text/html",
    whiff.headers: [
        ["Expires","Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"],
        ["Cache-Control","no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"],
        ["Cache-Control","post-check=0, pre-check=0"],
        ["Pragma","no-cache"]
        ]
/}}

<script>
//alert("!! RESPONSE RECIEVED");
errorNumber = 0;
fileUrl = "fileurl.png";
fileName = "filename.png";
customMsg = "";
window.parent.OnUploadCompleted(errorNumber, fileUrl, fileName, customMsg);
</script>
```

The {{env ...}} stuff at the top indicate the content type and
recommended HTTP headers to send.  The fileUrl should be the Url to
use to find the image on the server.

Here are the basic steps to get the html fragment which
generates the FCK editor widget. The only tricky part is you have to put the 
right client indentification into the os.environ -- it's ugly
but that's the way the FCK library works right now (I filed a bug
report).

```
import fckeditor # you must have the fck editor python support installed to use this module
import os

inputName = "myInputName" # the name to use for the input element in the form
basePath = "/server/relative/path/to/fck/installation/" # the location of FCK static files
if basePath[-1:]!="/":
        basePath+="/" # basepath must end in slash
oFCKeditor = fckeditor.FCKeditor(inputName)
oFCKeditor.BasePath = basePath
oFCKeditor.Height = 300 # the height in pixels of the editor
oFCKeditor.Value = "<h1>initial html to be editted</h1>"
os.environ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U;..." # or whatever
# there must be some way to figure out the user agent in Django right?
htmlOut = oFCKeditor.Create()
# insert htmlOut into your page where you want the editor to appear
return htmlOut
```

The above is untested, but it's based on the below which is tested.

Here is how to use FCK editor using mod-wsgi:
Technically it uses a couple features of WHIFF (see
[WHIFF.sourceforge.net](http://whiff.sourceforge.net)),
-- in fact it is part of the WHIFF distribution --
 but
the WHIFF features are easily removed.

I don't know how to install it in Django, but if
Django allows wsgi apps to be installed easily, you
should be able to do it.

NOTE: FCK allows the client to inject pretty much anything
into HTML pages -- you will want to filter the returned value for evil
attacks.
(eg: see whiff.middleware.TestSafeHTML middleware for
an example of how to do this).

```
    
"""
Introduce an FCK editor input element. (requires FCKeditor http://www.fckeditor.net/).

Note: this implementation can generate values containing code injection attacks if you
  don't filter the output generated for evil tags and values.
"""

import fckeditor # you must have the fck editor python support installed to use this module
from whiff.middleware import misc
import os

class FCKInput(misc.utility):
    def __init__(self,
                 inputName, # name for input element
                 basePath, # server relative URL root for FCK HTTP install
                 value = ""):  # initial value for input
        self.inputName = inputName
        self.basePath = basePath
        self.value = value
    def __call__(self, env, start_response):
        inputName = self.param_value(self.inputName, env).strip()
        basePath = self.param_value(self.basePath, env).strip()
        if basePath[-1:]!="/":
            basePath+="/"
        value = self.param_value(self.value, env)
        oFCKeditor = fckeditor.FCKeditor(inputName)
        oFCKeditor.BasePath = basePath
        oFCKeditor.Height = 300 # this should be a require!
        oFCKeditor.Value = value
        # hack around a bug in fck python library: need to put the user agent in os.environ
        # XXX this hack is not safe for multi threaded servers (theoretically)... need to lock on os.env
        os_environ = os.environ
        new_os_env = os_environ.copy()
        new_os_env.update(env)
        try:
            os.environ = new_os_env
            htmlOut = oFCKeditor.Create()
        finally:
            # restore the old os.environ
            os.environ = os_environ
        start_response("200 OK", [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
        return [htmlOut]

__middleware__ = FCKInput

def test():
    env = {
        "HTTP_USER_AGENT":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en-US; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080404 Firefox/2.0.0.14"
        }
    f = FCKInput("INPUTNAME", "/MY/BASE/PATH", "THE HTML VALUE TO START WITH")
    r = f(env, misc.ignore)
    print "test result"
    print "".join(list(r))

if __name__=="__main__":
    test()
```

See this working, for example, at

http://aaron.oirt.rutgers.edu/myapp/docs/W1500.whyIsWhiffCool.

btw: thanks.  I needed to look into this anyway.